# Confused about optional properties - How to write this code better?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift with Sprite Kit and currently have this snippet of code

```
class GameScene: SKScene
{
    // properties
    var mySprite: SKSpriteNode?
    //////////////////////////

    ...

    func initSprite()
    {
        let randomNumber = GenerateRandomNum() // some rand 0-2

        switch randomNumber
        {
            case 0:
                mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite1")
                mySprite.position = somePos
                self.addChild(mySprite!)
            case 1:
                mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite2")
                mySprite.position = somePos
                self.addChild(mySprite!)
            case 2:
                mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite3")
                mySprite.position = somePos
                self.addChild(mySprite!)
            default:
                println("Error")
        }

    }

}
```

I want to put the `self.addChild(mySprite!)` outside and below the `switch` statement so that I won't have to write it every time on each case. But the problem is, if I write it outside the `switch` statement, I get a runtime error when I call `initSprite()` due to `"found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".`

How do I write this code better so that I won't have to write `self.addChild(mySprite!)` in every case?

Comment: Better way to create variable is to unwrap it when you declare it `var mySprite: SKSpriteNode!`

Answer (score 1):

What about a lazy var?

```
class GameScene: SKScene
{
    // properties
    lazy var mySprite: SKSpriteNode = {
        let imageNames = [ "sprite1", "sprite2", "sprite3" ]
        let imageName = imageNames[ arc4random_uniform(3) ]

        let node = SKSpriteNode( imageNamed: imageName )
        self.addChild(node)
        node
    }
}
```

*mySprite* will always be non-nil, and will be assigned when it's first accessed. (Or adapt to be non-lazy.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mySprite: SKSpriteNode!


func initSprite()
    {
        let randomNumber = GenerateRandomNum() // some rand 0-2

        var imageName = nil // default image name here
        var position = nil // default position here

        switch randomNumber
        {
            case 0:
                imageName = "sprite1"
                position = pos
            case 1:
                imageName = "sprite1"
                position = pos
            case 2:
                imageName = "sprite1"
                position = pos
            default:
                println("Error")
        }
        if imageName != nil && position != nil
        {
           mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)
           mySprite.position = position
           self.addChild(mySprite!)
        }
    }
```

Here there is one time SKSpriteNode setting is done, and don't forget to provide default values, if no defaults required, then have a null check at the and while sprite creation.

Comment: This solution alters the logic: the sprite is always added even if the `default` case is executed - that might be an unwanted behavior

Comment: Note that the code doesn't compile - you missed to specify the type of 'imageName' and 'position'